# QTableWidget and QHeaderView CSS

Tags: css, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets

I cant find a way to theme the top left side of a QHeaderView. Maybe its part of QTableWidget, I cant tell...
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2hq2.png

```
History {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 black, stop:1 gray);
}

* {
    font: 500 12pt "Cantarell";
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 200);
}

QTableWidget {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 black, stop:1 blue);
}

QTableWidget::item {
    hborder: 5px solid rgba(68, 119, 170, 150);
    background-color:rgba(68, 119, 170, 125);
}

QHeaderView, QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 128);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The corner widget in a `QTableWidget` is implemented as a `QAbstractButton` and can be styled using the `QTableWidget QTableCornerButton::section` selector.

**Warning**: If you only set a `background-color` on a `QTableCornerButton`, the background may not appear unless you set the `border` property to some value. This is because, by default, the `QTableCornerButton` draws a native border which completely overlaps the background-color.

```
tableWidget.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget QTableCornerButton::section {"
    "background: red;"
    "border: 2px outset red;"
"}");
```